# Is it possible to query all emails over 90 days in exchange online using powershell?

Tags: powershell, email, office365, exchange-server

I have been tasked to export all emails older than 90 days from user mailboxes that are on extended email retention policies. The goal is to provide them with a list of emails that will be deleted once they are put back on a 90 day retention policy. Is it possible to pull that information using the exchange online powershell module?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that from an Exchange MRM perspective, retention age is not only calculated on arrival time. It is a nuanced topic, described here:
[How retention age is calculated in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/retention-age)

However, one approach to get messages that have a receive time matching your criteria (90 days) would be to use the Microsoft Graph [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) resource. You can then use the ReceivedDateTime filter, like this, with the PowerShell SDK module:

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId example.com
$UserId = 'mike@example.com'

$90DaysAgo = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-90)).GetDateTimeFormats("o")

$Uri = "v1.0/users/$userid/mailFolders/inbox/messages?`$filter=ReceivedDateTime le $90DaysAgo&`$top=1000"
$Messages = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method get -Uri $uri

$Messages.value | foreach {
    [pscustomobject]@{        
        createdDateTime = $_.createdDateTime
        sender = $_.sender.emailAddress.address
        subject = $_.subject
    }
}
```

Please understand however, depending on how your policies are configured, you'd need to look at mailbox content other than just messages. If you want more than 1000 results, you'll need to loop through [pages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/microsoft-graph-mailbag-a-deeper-look-into-the-microsoft-graph-powershell-sdk/#paging), but the above should get you started.